# Проект базы для мессенджера

Tags: база-данных, postgresql

пытаюсь спроектиповать мессенджер по аналогии вк, но не могу понять, как вложить групповой чат?

dialogs

```
id 
type
createdAt
```

dialog_users

```
dislog_id
user_id
```

dialog_messages

```
dialog_id
user_id
text
isRead
```

dialog_message_files

```
dialog_message_id
type 
file
fileSrc
```

Comment: Попробуй юзера к диалогу через m2m таблицу

Comment: Подправил вопрос, вот так?

Comment: Да. Ещё в эту таблицу добавь айди последних доставленного и прочитанного сообщения - чтобы отобразить пользователю с какого места читать

Comment: Не совсем понял, ещё два поля, last_message_id и read_ message_id в таблицу dialog_users?

Comment: чтоб доставлять срез сообщений когда пользователь подключается. и чтоб индикатор непрочитанных повесить

Comment: а можно подробнее как это работает, не до конца понимаю алгоритм